# Convert python variable data into JSON format

Tags: python, mysql, json

So I have created a script, where I connect to my PHPMyAdmin SQL database and perform a query to pull two columns, one column contains timestamp and the second column contains a decimal value.
These are currently stored in the variable ‘result3’ as depicted in my code snippet below.

```
mycursor3 = mydb.cursor()
mycursor3.execute("select INTERVAL_DATETIME, TOTALCLEARED from mms.P5MIN_UNITSOLUTION where DUID='FINLYSF1' AND RUN_DATETIME= (SELECT MAX(RUN_DATETIME) from mms.P5MIN_UNITSOLUTION where DUID='FINLYSF1' )")
result3 = mycursor3.fetchall()

for row in result3:
    print(row)
```

How can I convert the data stored in this ‘result3’ variable into a JSON format so that it has the structure shown below, in my python script:

[image: Convert data from python variable format to JSON format]

Comment: Have you tried `print(json.dumps(row))`?

Comment: @wjm, I found a tutorial using that which should do the trick, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the print(json.dumps(row)) variable allows the necessary json creation of the data.